# Profile2 restrict main profile

Tags: users

I really don't know how to fix this so whats why im posting this over here.

Im using Profile2 for my profiles The Main profile is for authenicated users, lets can this User A.

I have also another profile type, with a seperate registration form, lets call this user B.

When user B wants to edit his profile, he can also choose to edit his main profile (profile for user A), i figured out that because user B is authenticaded he can automaticly edit his main profile, and his own profile (specially for user B's). How can i prevent user B for edit his main profile?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create two roles, one for A and one for B - then you can restrict access to different profiles in permissions under admin/people/permissions .

You could use Rules to assign the appropriate role based on selections during registration, and use the 'After Saving a new user account' trigger.

Comment: Geoff thanks for your quick reply, your answer helped me a lot